# HTML image module for e-mail

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm having an odd issue, I'm making a module for a HTML email, where there's 4 small images to the left and 1 big image to the right.

It all looks good, but in some email clients, like Yahoo, Outlook.com, Gmail and outlook 2000-2003, I get an approximately 3px whitespace between the small images. Setting the margin and padding to 0 doesn't help, and I simply cannot see, where the whitespace is coming from.

Here's the HTML I've so far for the module:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="resize320" width="600">
<tr valign="top">
    <td width="25%">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://image.e.selected.com/lib/fe8813727d6d037e76/m/2/fa2c635f-b36e-4280-87dd-4005ac367f77.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 150px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0 0 0 0;" width="150"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://image.e.selected.com/lib/fe8813727d6d037e76/m/2/fa2c635f-b36e-4280-87dd-4005ac367f77.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 150px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0 0 0 0;" width="150">
    </td>
    <td width="25%">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://image.e.selected.com/lib/fe8813727d6d037e76/m/2/fa2c635f-b36e-4280-87dd-4005ac367f77.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 150px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0 0 0 0;" width="150"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://image.e.selected.com/lib/fe8813727d6d037e76/m/2/fa2c635f-b36e-4280-87dd-4005ac367f77.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 150px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0 0 0 0;" width="150">
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://image.e.selected.com/lib/fe8813727d6d037e76/m/2/3c2b121f-b627-44e6-84c3-39465bd4e72c.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px;" width="300">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here's the CSS I have in my template:

```
<style type="text/css">
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#000;
}
a.disable-link {
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
}
body {
 width:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
div, p, a, li, td {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}
.ii a {
 text-decoration: none !important;
 color: transparent !important;
}
.ReadMsgBody .ExternalClass a:link {
 text-decoration: none !important;
 color: transparent !important;
}
.yshortcuts {
 text-decoration: none !important;
 color: transparent !important;
}
/*Fix for making placeholders visible in editor*/
 ul.editorSectionEmpty {
 min-width: 200px !important;
}
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 720px) {
table[class=nomob], td[class=nomob], div[class=nomob], span[class=nomob] {
   display: none !important;
  }
  table[class=resizedynamic], td[class=resizedynamic], td[class=resizedynamic] img {
   width: 100% !important;
   height: auto !important;
  }

table[class=resize320], td[class=resize320] {
 width:320px !important;
 height:auto !important;
}
td[class=resizeimg320] img {
 width:320px !important;
 height:auto !important;
}
td[class=resizeimg200] img {
 width:200px !important;
 height:auto !important;
}
td[class=colsplit] {
 width:320px !important;
 float:left !important;
}
td[class=mobilepadding] {
 padding: 0 10px !important;
}
font[class=textresize] {
 font-size:14px !important;
}
table[class=resize280], td[class=resize280] {
 width:280px !important;
 height:auto !important;
}
td[class=resize75] {
 width:75px !important;
 height:auto !important;
}
table[class=resize320mob], td[class=resize320mob] {
 width:320px !important;
 height:20px !important;
}
a[class="disable-link"] {
 pointer-events: auto !important;
 cursor: auto !important;
}
td[class=resizeimg160] img {
 width:160px !important;
 height:auto !important;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: add `display:block` in `img` tag and try

Comment: In your `img` tag add `display:table`. It would remove the extra spaces.

Comment: Display:block works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need **more CSS rules to reset `<table>`'s behavior**. Trying adding this to the `<style>`:

```
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
table,
td {
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}
/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
table {
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
table table table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
```